# Corda enums serialization and PersistentState

Tags: corda

I use Corda 4.1 and kotlin. My goal is to store some data to Corda databse using Persistence API and then do some queries(I follow the doc https://docs.corda.net/api-persistence.html ). I have small problem with querying enumerated types.

This enum

```
@CordaSerializable
enum class MyEnum {    
    A,
    B,
    C
}
```

is stored in the database table as integer values
0
1
2
And it looks like A corresponds 0, B corresponds 1, and C correponds 2.

But I do not see any explicit mappings. What rules are used to serialize enum values? can they be changed with some annotations?

Is there any simple way of ensuring that **A** enum value  will be always saved as **0** in the database? Is it possible to persist just "A", "B", "C" directly instead of numbers?

I could do this maually implenmenting this logic in **generateMappedObject** function, but I am curious what is the right way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here in the Kotlin specification: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/enum-classes.html#working-with-enum-constants

Ordinals are allocated by the order in which they are declared within the Enum, and you can access the ordinal programmatically by calling `MyEnum.A.ordinal`

It doesn't look like there is any easy way to explicitly allocate ordinals like in C# where you can say `enum { A = 2, B = 1, C = 0 }`

You can also tell Hibernate to persist the mapping as a string by defining your column in the mapped entity as:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "table_containing_en_enum"
    class MyClass {

        @Column(name = "enum")
        @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        val enum: MyEnum, 

        ...
    }
```